# Как получить значение поля у которого другие значения равны условию?

Tags: postgresql

Мне нужно получить id папки, у которой все статусы файлов  равны 3.

```
file_id  status   folder_id
1          3         1
2          1         2 
3          3         1 
4          3         1
5          3         2
```

То есть у всех файлов папки folder_id 1, status равен 3. А у папки folder_id 2, 
не все имеют статус 3.
Поэтому мне нужно чтобы вернулся запрос  folder_id равный 1. Не знаю куда копать, это как то связано с группировкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select folder_id
  from tab
 group by folder_id
 having max(status)=3 and min(status)=3
```

Comment: А если в статусе может оказаться `null`?

Comment: @Yaant тогда добавить еще условие `count(1)=count(status)`