# Как в таблице MYSQL выбрать только последние строки по заданным параметрам?

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

Подсобите новичку. Ситуация очень похожая на ту, которая [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708692/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E). Только статусы у меня могут принимать 3 значения (1, 2 и 3).

Запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_lessons_uls_welcomecourse_access 
WHERE wp_lessons_uls_welcomecourse_access.status IN (1,2,3) 
group by userId, lessonNum
having max(status) IN (1,2) and min(status)=1
```

**Задача:** 
нужно выбрать id только тех строк, где у userId и lessonNum последний добавленный статус (status) = 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблемы:**

- если у userId, lessonNum последняя строка имеет  статус 2, то id этих строк тоже попадают в выборку. И это то, над чем уже вторые сутки бьюсь. Знаю, что попадает, потому что это прописано тут: `having max(status) IN (1,2)`
- Если написать `having max(status) = 1`, то из выборки выпадают id строк, у которых статус принимал значение 2;
- Если написать `having max(status) = 2`, то отображаются только те id, где статус принимал значение 2;

Перелопатил уже всё, что нашел по подходящим темам на этом сайте. Скорее всего, конечно, ищу неправильно, потому что толком не могу сформулировать, что мне надо найти.

Comment: Понятие "последний" существует только после того, как указана сортировка, и только при условии, что ключ сортировки уникален. В заданном вопросе это понятие не существует - даже несмотря  на неявную сортировку при группировке.

Comment: Так же обратите внимание, что `select *` абсолютно не совместим с group by. В данном случае в выборку у вас попадут нужные поля userId и lessonNum, но все остальные будут взяты из случайной записи (и даже возможно, что из разных !) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569 По поводу "последней" строки см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/412929/194569 и более сложный (но иногда нужный), вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496532/194569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike), благодарю за комментарий. Прям выручило!
Полдня разбирался с теорией про группировки, алиасы и т.п., но в итоге всё зараболо!

Для тех, кто столкнётся с аналогичной проблемой - [вот статья (Группировка в MySQL)](https://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html), где подробно разжёвано, что да как делать в подобной ситуации.

Решение получилось длинным, поэтому коротко суть:

1. Собрал все id, у которых status = 1. Добавил их в **массив 1**;
2. Собрал последние id для каждого userId. Добавил их в **массив 2**;
3. Собрал в **массив 3** все id, у которых статус может принимать значения 1 и 2 с условием, что они должны присутствовать в массивах 1 и 2;
4. Сделал конечную выборку из **массива 3** с тем условием, что статус обязательно должен быть равен 1;

Уверен, что можно сделать стройнее и изящнее. Но главное, что всё работает именно так, как задумано! Ещё раз благодарю за помощь!