# Как исключить из выборки значения полей

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Допустим, есть одна таблица, которая состоит из двух полей: номер материала и статус. У одного материала может быть 2 статуса (например 1 и 2) или только 1 статус. Нужно написать запрос, который выгрузит из базы данных именно те материалы у которых статус только 2. Т.е нужно вывести материалы со статусом 2, исключая те материалы где присутствует материалы со статусом 1. 
Из картинку следует, что ожидаемый ответ 1011

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить значение поля у которого другие значения равны условию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708692/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: Да, схожая ситуация. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
with t(mat, status) as 
(
  select 'A', 2 from dual
  union all
  select 'A', 1 from dual
  union all
  select 'B', 2 from dual
  union all
  select 'B', 2 from dual
)
select distinct mat, status from t
where mat not in (select mat from t where status = 1);
```

Либо вариант с not exists